# ZF2 - Missing instance/object for parameter driver error

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm getting the following error message with zend framework 2 application:

> Missing instance/object for parameter driver for
>   Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::__construct (File:
>   C:\xampp\zendfw2\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Di\Di.php:856)

My code is the following:
autoload/local.php:

```
return array(
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'driver' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'connection' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'connectionInfo' => array(
                    'dsn' => "mysql:dbname=zendtest;host=localhost",
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

module.config.php:

```
return array(
'di' => array(
        'Test2\Model\ManagerAbstract' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'adapter'  => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
            ),
        ),
),
...);
```

ManagerAbstract.php:

```
namespace Test2\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAwareInterface;

abstract class ManagerAbstract implements AdapterAwareInterface 
{
protected $adapter;

public function setDbAdapter(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}

public function getUserList() {
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from(array('u'=>'tsrv_user'));
    $select->where(array('username' => $username));
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $results = $statement->execute();

    return $results;
}
}
```

User.php:

```
namespace Test2\Model;

class User extends ManagerAbstract
{
public function __construct() {

}
}
```

And I call it in the Controller like:

```
$di = new Di();
$model = $di->get('Test2\Model\User');
$model->getUserList();
```

Can you please help me by pointing out what causes the error message?

Comment: Rename method setDbAdapter -> setAdapter in ManagerAbstract class

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` in your `Di` configuration isn't correct.

You can find here a correct way how to do that : [Zend\Db Adapter instantiation through Zend Framework 2 Di](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/1360533).